# Is there cost effective file synchronization service for large teams with not much data?

Tags: webapp-rec

I love Dropbox. But Dropbox for Teams seems most appropriate for Teams with few members and a lot of data. I'm working with a team that has lots of members, but not much data, so the Dropbox pricing seems high.

Does anybody have a recommendation for a file synchronization server for teams with lots of people, but not a lot of data (<50GB)?

Comment: How many is 'lots of users'?

Comment: What does your team do?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest a different approach. Get a VPS ([Linode](http://linode.com) is good, and you'll get 20 GB ~ $200 yearly) and setup [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). You are not very clear on your requirements, but if it is just for syncing between different users then this approach is good. Plus you can add remove unlimited users.

Answer (score 0):

If you have really a lot of people, but not much data, you might want to look into rolling your own solution on top of Amazon S3.  See for example, [this SuperUser topic](https://superuser.com/questions/132728/replacing-dropbox-with-amazon-s3-ssl-gpg-truecrypt-mounting-on-osx), or using software like [SyncAny](http://www.syncany.org/) (to be released soon).